# ¿Cómo establecer valores a elementos por índices?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero saber si se puede hacer algo similar en `Javascript(jquery)` como en C#, ejemplo:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Esta {0}.  El valor es {1}.", "es una prueba", 42));
//Imprime: Esta es una prueba. El valor es 42.
```

Según los indices, los valores se le pasan del mismo orden.
Y quiero saber si se puede hacer algo parecido pero en jquery, por ejemplo:

```
$('#label1, #label2, #label3').html(valorLabel1, valorLabel2, valorLabel3);
```

Quiero hacer esto para no tener que escribir una linea para cada uno, y como todos comparten el `.html()`, se me hizo mejor intentar hacerlo de esa manera. Pero no sé si exista ese tipo de funcionalidad.

Comment: en este hilo hay varias implementaciones https://stackoverflow.com/a/4256130/1423096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente se pueda optimizar un poco, para reemplazar los inner de varios elementos, con una lista de parámetros prueba con esto:

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  variosInnerHTML: function(...a) {
   return this.each(function(i) {
      $(this).html(a[i%a.length]);
    });
  }
});

var valorLabel1 = "etiqueta 1";
var valorLabel2 = "etiqueta 2";
var valorLabel3 = "etiqueta 3";

$(function(){
  $("#dale").on('click', function(){
    $("#label1, #label2, #label3, #label4").variosInnerHTML(valorLabel1, valorLabel2, valorLabel3);
    $("span").variosInnerHTML(valorLabel1, valorLabel2, valorLabel3).addClass("verde");
  })  
});
```

```css
label {
  color:red;
  background-color:#fe0;
}

span {
  color:red;
  background-color:#fafafa;
  }
label, span {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:2px 5px;
  border:1px dashed red;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.verde {
 color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Prueba de cambiar valores a etiquetas usando ID <label id="label1">uno</label>, <label id="label2">dos</label> y
<label id="label3">tres</label>. y uno mas <label id="label4">cuatro</label>
</p>

<p>Prueba de cambiar valores usando TAG <span>uno</span>, <span>dos</span> y
<span>tres</span>. y uno mas <span>cuatro</span>
</p>

<button id="dale">reemplazar textos</button>
```

Comment: Perfecto, eso buscaba, muchas gracias... Podrías explicarme qué es lo que hace la función de variosInnerHTML? no me quedó del todo claro

Comment: extiendo el jquery para que a la lista de elementos que viene se le apliquen los html dados por los parametros en orden, si hay mas elementos que parametros el index vuelve a 0 (`i%a.length`), el `...a` es para armar un array con los parametros que vienen sin tener que saber cuantos son, a cada elemento lo retorno modificado asi que debería funcionar cualquier chain que venga despues

Comment: ahí lo edité para demostrar el encadenado de cosas (reemplaza y le aplica una clase)

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes realizar declarando 2 variables, que contengan los valores solicitados; posterior por medio de template strings imprimir el valor del modo siguiente

```js
let prueba = 'es una prueba'
let valor = 42

console.log(`Esta ${prueba}. El valor es ${valor}`)
//"Esta es una prueba. El valor es 42"
```

> Como notas para imprimir variables dentro de las template strings hago
>   uso de las comillas invertidas y las variables con esta estructura
>   ${variable} para que su impresión en pantalla sea dinámica

Comment: ok, pero  cómo lo implemento para esto `$('#label1, #label2, #label3').html(valorLabel1, valorLabel2, valorLabel3);`?